# How can I use my custom ImageView with DataBinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-databinding, android-jetpack

So I checked this [codelab by Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-andoid-kotlin-training-custom-views/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) for creating a custom view `RatioImageView`. It simply extends the ImageView and overrides the `OnMeasure()` method according to device's viewport's aspect ratio. The code for the same is:

```
class RatioImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val VP_HEIGHT = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    private val VP_WIDTH = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    private val HWR: Float = VP_HEIGHT.toFloat()/VP_WIDTH.toFloat() //height to width ratio


    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)*HWR).toInt())
    }
}
```

Then I am using this in ListItem view as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <com.example.myapp.RatioImageView
            android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="image holder"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="#757575"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Then in the Adapter, I am using `DataBinding` to update the views with content as follows:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.apply {

              //loadImage() is an extension function added to ImageView class
              target.loadImage(UiUtil.getCustomUrl(photos[position].urls.fullImage, height, width))
       
            root.setOnClickListener {
                handleClick(position)
            }
        }
}
```

During building, it shows the following error:

> Cannot access class 'RatioImageView'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

i.e. for the line in which `target.loadImage(...)` is written in **OnBindViewHolder()**

Also, if I don't use DataBinding for the root layout, then it works fine.

So the question is what needs to be added to `RatioImageView`? To make it work with DataBinding, considering that here I don't require an XML layout to be associated with the View class.

Here's the `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeItemHolder {
        return HomeItemHolder(ItemPhotoListLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
}
```

And below is the `ViewHolder` class:

```
inner class HomeItemHolder (val binding: ItemPhotoListLayoutBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
}
```

Also here is the repo in case my code is missing something over here: https://github.com/prafullmishra/CustomImageView

Comment: Is your ```com.example.myapp.RatioImageView``` in the xml is similar as class package name?

Comment: I don't find any problem. Can you add more details of your `Adapter` and is this the complete implementation of `RatioImageView`?

Comment: @NarekHayrapetyan yes

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I left out rest of the adapter for brevity. Main logic lies in this only, where it is unable to access the `target` RatioImageView through `holder.binding`, which is what I intend to solve.

Comment: How did you initialize `binding` in ViewHolder? Can you show your `ViewHolder` with `onCreatedViewHolder` implementation? I ask as it works for me

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I have added `onCreateViewHolder()` and `ViewHolder`, please check

Comment: Can you show your `import` block in adapter file?

Comment: change id of `"target"` at `RatioImageView` and `holder.binding.apply {` to something else. `target` may already be a property or method of binding base class.

Comment: There are horrible problems when you use data binding in custom view, I faced more and more, then decided to forget using databinding in custom view.

Comment: @sma6871 Never say never :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in the code sample you posted on Github.  Actually, this one was tricky to solve from the snippet you posted, but the error was correctly indicating a problem with the class name.

Your XML referred to the class 
`com.example.bindingcustomimageview.CustomImage.RatioImageView`.  Without knowing anything more, `RatioView` looks like it's a public inner class of `CustomImage` in the package `com.example.bindingcustomimageview`.

But it wasn't.  It was the class `RatioImageView` in the package `com.example.bindingcustomimageview.CustomImage` (where "CustomImage" is an uppercase package name).  You can fix it quickly by dragging `RatioImageView` into the same package as your MainActivity, and everything will work correctly.

To avoid confusions like this in the future, don't name your packages with upper case names.

Comment: Such a small problem, hiding in plain sight! Thanks for saving my day! (and my app too :P )

Answer (score 0):

What attribute in your xml are you trying to bind data to?
Maybe you want to bind an image to the `android:src` attribute?
In that case:

1. Add `<variable name="image" type="Drawable"/>` inside of `<data>` tags
2. Include a [binding expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data) for the `src` attribute, for example `android:id="@{image}"`
3. Try the following:

   ```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
   holder.binding.apply {

       this.image = loadImage(UiUtil.getCustomUrl(photos[position].urls.fullImage, height, width))

       root.setOnClickListener {
           handleClick(position)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nope, I don't intent to bind any property through XML

Answer (score 0):

Any custom view should have at least 3 different kinds of constructor implementations which you need to provide before you can access it conveniently:

1. The one with 1 parameter: `RatioImageView(context)`
2. The one with 2 parameters: `RatioImageView(context, attrs)`
3. The one with 3 parameters: `RatioImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)`

While `RatioImageView` only have the one with 3 parameters which implements `ImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)`. That's why you get that error. You need to define the other 2 constructors as well.

Comment: Helpful, but I have default values in place for the constructor values. And with Kotlin's constructor overloading, this is equivalent to declaring 3 constructors like we had to in Java.